# Использование наследника от QGraphicsView в MainWindow и его использование

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте.

Пишу приложение на Qt, столкнулся с проблемой. У меня имеется класс, унаследованный от QGraphicsView, в нем реализована необходимая функционально, на всякий случай код конструктора этого элемента:

```
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);
    setScene(scene);
    setCacheMode(CacheBackground);
    setViewportUpdateMode(BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
    setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

В этом классе также реализована соответствующие функции, которые реагируют на нажатие кнопки мыши и создание в соответствующем месте точек.

Также есть, собственно, класс MainWindow (главное окно, которое и стартует при запуске приложения), в этом классе также есть указатель типа этого моего наследника от QGraphicsView. Собственно в чем задача - необходимо каким-либо образом сделать так, чтобы мой этот класс (наследник от QGraphicsView) "поместился" на MainForm, занимая всё пространство и хорошо функционировал.

Я пробовал это реализовать следующим образом - в конструкторе MainForm дописал:

```
mywidget = new MyGraphicsViewWidget(this);
mywidge->setGeometry(0, ui->menuBar->height(), width(), height());
```

Однако это не дало желаемого эффекта. В результате этих операций при запуске таки видно, что на форме есть этот мой класс-наследник от QGraphicsView, однако:

- Если я клацаю по этой области, то точки, которые должны рисоваться в позиции курсора - смещены куда-то вниз вправо.
- Если развернуть окно на весь экран - эта область QGraphicsView остается неизменной.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы этот класс нормально функционировал, т.е. подгонял свой размер, когда форма его меняет, не теряя своего содержимого (нарисованных точек), а также отрисовывал точки на нужных позициях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
mywidget = new MyGraphicsViewWidget(this);
this->setCentralWidget(mywidget);
```

Это заставит ваш виджет растягиваться вместе с окном

Comment: Спасибо, проблему с растягиванием действительно решило.


Осталось решить проблему с тем, чтобы точки рисовались в позиции, где я нажимаю кнопку мыши, а не в смещенных позициях (чем больше растягиваю окно - тем больше смещение).

Comment: Тут я вам не помощник т.к. этого никогда не делал чтобы знать о подводных камнях, да и перехват-отрисовку вы не привели, хотя фаза про увеличение смещения вместе с окном наводит на мысль что где-то захардкожен неправильный размер окна и\или неверный отсчет начала координат (или у вас два разных начала для события мыши и для отрисовки), а рисуется все в относительных величинах размера экрана.

Comment: Я могу и больший пример кода привести, но там не принципиально, в классе, наследуемом от QGraphicsView просто навсего переопределяется onMouseKeyPressed (ну или как там он точно называется, сейчас под рукой кода нет), я не знаю почему смещения идут.